# A very basic issue with routes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby and while creating a sample application found out an issue that whenever I go to http://127.0.0.1:3000/people/index by default show action is executed and index is taken as a parameter. This is server log:

```
 Started GET "/people/index" for
 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-23 18:43:01 +0500 Processing by PeopleController#show as
 HTML Parameters: {"id"=>"index"}
```

I have this in my route file:

```
root :to => "people#index"   
resources :people
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

What is going on here and how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 5):

The route

```
resources :people
```

creates "sub"-routes

```
get    '/people'          => 'people#index'
get    '/people/new'      => 'people#new'
post   '/people'          => 'people#create'
get    '/people/:id'      => 'people#show'
get    '/people/:id/edit' => 'people#edit'
put    '/people/:id'      => 'people#update'
delete '/people/:id'      => 'people#destroy'
```

Actually, all of these sub-routes include `(.:format)` at the end of the recognized path.

The path `/people/index` would be recognized by the route `/people/:id`, mapping to the action `#show`.

The path `/people` would be recognized by the route `/people`, mapping to the action `#index`.

Use the URL helpers `people_path` and `people_url` for the `/people` route.

To get Rails to travel backward in time to before it espoused REST and to understand `/people/index`, do this:

```
resources :people do
  get :index => 'people#index'
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. Now resources :people makes more sense to me. Now the question is how can I access action index when I directly go to /people/index. Should I add another rule get '/people/index' => 'people#index' ??

Comment: The new **Rails Way**, the RESTful way, is that `/people` gets you the people index. There is no longer any need for `/people/index`, which is a remnant from a prior version of Rails and is more closely representative of the Rails MVC architecture than representative of the REST philosophy. It's one of those "Don't Do It" things. If you really need to do it (because you have a backwards compatibility issue with other websites pointing to your `/people/index`, see my edit.

Comment: Hmm.  I might rewrite that as a redirect route. `match "/people/index", :to => redirect(people_path)`

Comment: Generally, you should not use `match` unless you also use `:via =>`. The reason is that `match` without `:via =>` makes a route that recognizes all HTTP verbs. You should only have routes that recognize a white list of HTTP verbs - generally, just `GET`.

Comment: I have changed my route as you said i.e. 
  root :to => "people#index"
  resources :people do
    get :index => 'people#index'
  end
but now I am unable to start the server. It says: `method_missing': undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in         super C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48

Answer (score 0):

You might want to watch [this Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3).

A couple things to keep in mind when working with your routes:

1. `rake routes` dumps the map of URLs to your controllers
2. When providing backwards compatibility, redirect the user to the correct path

I personally have yet to upgrade my app to Rails 3, and I'll be dragging my feet until I really need to do it (just got it out the door not too long ago).  In Rails 2.x you had resource routes, but if you kept the default controller/action/id route it would fall through and resolve.  It appears that is no longer the case in Rails 3.  Essentially your resource routes handle all URLs in that resource namespace (/people in your case).

To provide backwards compatibility, I would add a redirect route to resolve that incompatibility.

```
match "/people/index", :to => redirect("/people")
```

The main reason for that is to prevent users from saving an incorrect URL for their personal links--while allowing legacy users to still be able to get where they meant to go.

**Edit**: New answer, removed pointing out the typo in the question.

Comment: > was added by mistake when trying to format the post here at SO

Comment: I changed my answer after a bit more digging in and your comment about the typo.

Comment: I tried root 
  :to => "people#index"
  resources :people
  match "/people/index", :to => redirect("/people")
and it gave me this error:
BSON::InvalidObjectId in PeopleController#show in app/controllers/people_controller.rb:63:in `show' 
which means that again show is being called